# Javasrcipt - Browser console error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined"

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, console, jsx

I'm trying to export a function which is in the file `jogar.js` to the file `index.js`, but when I open the browser (Firefox) it appears this error "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined". Here's the code:

`index.js`

```
import Jogar from "./jogar"

function Header() {
    return(
        <header>
            <h1>Morto ou vivo!</h1>
        </header>
    )
} 

function Section() {
    return(
        <section>            
            <h2>Carregue no botão para jogar!</h2>
            <div className="res">
                <input type="button" className="btn_esq" value="Morto"/>
                <input type="button" className="btn_dir" value="Vivo"/> <br/>
            </div>
            <input type="button" className="btn_jogar" value="Jogar" onClick={Jogar}/>

        </section>
    )
}

<Jogar/>

function Footer() {
    return(
        <footer>&copy; 2023</footer>
    )
}

function Pagina(){
    return(
        <div>    
            <Header/> 
            <Section/>
            <Footer/>
        </div>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<Pagina/>, document.getElementById("root"))
```

`jogar.js`

```
export default function Jogar() {
    return(
        window.alert("funcionou")
    )
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="index.js" type="text/babel"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

NOTE: The code is in portuguese, so if you don't understand something, use the google translator or comment your question in the comments section above

Comment: I don't see a mention of `require` anywhere in the code you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**type should be `module`** for ES6 module system

```
<script type="module" src="index.js"></script>
```

If you use module system then the script type must be module in index.html. This can resolve your issue.

[Detailed DOC HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules)

Comment: now it appears other error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' " on line 4

Comment: Remove this <Jogar/>, because it is not a component

Comment: So how I use it?

Comment: You already using it in section input button onclick